# Ubuntu 20.04, Nvidia - unmet Dependencies error [Installation]

Tags: nvidia, 20.04, graphics, xorg, dependencies

I've been trying to install nvidia drivers in ubuntu-20.04 and "sudo ubuntu-drivers install" gives me the following error.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nvidia-driver-460 : Depends: libnvidia-gl-460 (= 460.73.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libnvidia-extra-460 (= 460.73.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: nvidia-compute-utils-460 (= 460.73.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libnvidia-encode-460 (= 460.73.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: nvidia-utils-460 (= 460.73.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-460 (= 460.73.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libnvidia-cfg1-460 (= 460.73.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libnvidia-ifr1-460 (= 460.73.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libnvidia-fbc1-460 (= 460.73.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Recommends: nvidia-settings but it is not going to be installed
                     Recommends: libnvidia-compute-460:i386 (= 460.73.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)
                     Recommends: libnvidia-decode-460:i386 (= 460.73.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)
                     Recommends: libnvidia-encode-460:i386 (= 460.73.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)
                     Recommends: libnvidia-ifr1-460:i386 (= 460.73.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)
                     Recommends: libnvidia-fbc1-460:i386 (= 460.73.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)
                     Recommends: libnvidia-gl-460:i386 (= 460.73.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have tried several methods from different forums and no luck.

"sudo apt --fix-broken install" does not solve the problem.

I have tried the solutions from the link given below.

[How to solve unmet dependencies when installing Nvidia drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/260504/how-to-solve-unmet-dependencies-when-installing-nvidia-drivers)

But, "sudo apt-get install --fix-broken xorg-video-abi-11 xserver-xorg-core -y"
command also didn't seem to solve the problem. Tried installing from nvidia PPA and the issue persists.

I have attached the system details below.

```
OS: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS x86_64 
Host: Nitro AN515-43 V1.10 
Kernel: 5.8.0-53-generic 
Uptime: 31 mins 
Packages: 2293 (dpkg), 13 (snap) 
Shell: bash 5.0.17 
Resolution: 1920x1080 
DE: GNOME 
Terminal: gnome-terminal 
CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 3550H with Radeon Vega Mobile Gfx (8) @ 2.100 
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650 Mobile / Max-Q 
GPU: AMD ATI 05:00.0 Picasso 
Memory: 3275MiB / 5944MiB
```

Comment: You put your own dependencies in the install, not the two from the old question you referenced.    Just cut and paste from the error output, no need to type them all.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it is similar to an issue that Pop_OS! users were facing recently. System76 has already patched this for Pop_OS! and has alerted Ubuntu developers. I think this will be solved in a couple of weeks- sit tight.
See this: https://www.reddit.com/r/pop_os/comments/n5j8c0/nvidia_driver_4652402_issues/

Comment: That link refers to the lack of i386 packages for the 465 driver -- nothing to do with the 460.73.01 packages in the Original Posting.